# Trigonometric Curves, Finding Range

Tags: trigonometry, curves

Sketch the graph of $y=2\sin x + 1$ for intervals $0° \leq x \leq 360°$. Hence state the range of values of $x$ in this interval which satisfies the inequality $2\sin x + 1 \geq 0$.

The graph sketching part is easy but please can anyone explain how to find the range. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Could you define what "range" means in this context?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply asking you the following:
For what values of $x$ is $\sin x \geq -\dfrac{1}{2}$? Does that help?

Comment: Yes it did help a little bit. SinX >= -1/2 how do you find the actual values of X?

Comment: Plot the curve. For what values in $[0,2\pi]$, $\sin x = -1/2$? Then see for yourself where it is bigger than $-1/2$

Comment: You are not suppose to draw the actual graph but only sketch it roughly. Then the range should be determined by calculations.

Comment: Do you know anything about inverse $\sin(x)$, or $\sin^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

> The graph sketching part is easy

If you have sketched the graph y=2sin x+1, then the question requires the values for which $y\ge 0$ i.e.,the regions of graph above x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the equation $$2\sin x+1=0$$ in the specified range, you get $x=210°,330°.$ You can check that $2\sin x+1$ becomes $1$ at both endpoints of the given interval; thus by continuity it follows that the quantity is negative only for $x$ strictly between $210°$ and $330°.$ This gives you what you want.